# How can we improve the situation around recognizable low-level vendor-specific solutions (e.g. on Android)?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

After two-month development of Android low-level stuff, usually followed by daily visits to SO and certain related groups/forums, I've found an unusually high chance of getting "You are doing what is forbidden"-type answer.

From my point of view: it's my phone, it runs Linux, it can run binaries, it has some 3rdparty code within used to support vendor-specific things like dual-SIM, like injecting audio data to call, a ton of my friends and a billion of other people has same phone model from same vendor, I can open beer bottle with it and lose warranty and don't care, and there is no need to get anything from Play Store...

From the crowd of high-rep specialists: **you are doing not what is allowed in public SDK, thus there is no answer**.

It can be understood that low-level playing with iOS involves a clear violation of EULA (someone said "reverse engineering"?), and Apple is major influencer, trend-setting and taming the young hackers in bulk rates. But Android is open-source, why not to modify anything?

Isn't that clear, that if a major number of people has something that can be modified, a VALID answer for question SHOULD include a detailed description on what can be changed in current codebase to work and what was already done by most popular vendors (HTC? Samsung? all that MTK - THL/Zopo?)

I wonder why any solution/feature request, unofficial to main codebase, is stopped at the point of "not available in the master trunk"?

Samples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12259378/438039; https://stackoverflow.com/a/13985100/438039

---

My point: "unofficial" != "unknown" + "unsupported".
How about introducing something short and nice to become `recognizable-android-platform-extensions` tag?

Comment: I don't quite understand your final sentence. Are you suggesting tags such as `htc-extensions`, and so on?

Comment: your samples don't specify the vendor, meaning that answers can't recommend vendor-specific solutions, only that the solutions are neccessarily vendor-specific.

Comment: Have you actually got such comment on your question or you are simply speculating what some bad-attituded community members could potentially answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way of doing that is *improving the questions*. Neither of the examples you give are good questions for getting low level answers, because they don't *ask* for low level answers.

**Example 1:** [Call logging with Dual SIM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11823462/752320)

This is a straightforward request to separate the call logs based on which SIM is used. However, it is completely unclear that the asker even realizes this would be a vendor-specific answer. For instance, he asks, "*Can Android do something like that ... or do I have to change Android version?*"

The correct answer is *no*, it can't. You might be able to do that *on an Android phone*, but *Android* can't do that, and simply changing to another version won't help it. You need device-specific help. Please forgive the answerer for not listing the exact code for every model of Android device, but I believe that falls under the category of "too broad".

**Example 2:** [Call from second sim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13231962/752320)

Basically the same as the first, and suffers from the same "What do you know?" problem. However, this time one of the answers gives an actual *solution*, at least for a certain model of phone. The other answer says the same as before, you need to get in touch with the manufacturer.

Also, as Jan mentions in the comments above, neither of these examples mention what type of device they are using *at all*. How is anyone supposed to give low-level advice without knowing any of the specifics?

**Your recent dual-sim question:** [Android: what vendor-specific methods are known for dual-SIM phones to detect a SIM used for SMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21039753/752320)

I assume that this is what prompted this question. This *is* a better question, but it could be better still.

First, make it *clear* that you know this can't be done with the standard SDK. On first reading, it sounds like you're looking for *standard* ways of doing it. If the question doesn't make it very clear that you already *know* the API doesn't provide this, you're going to get a response of "the API doesn't provide this," because 99% of users/askers only care about what the API provides, so it's more likely that questions are looking for an API solution.

Second, get rid of the "listiness" of the question at the end. If you want an HTC solution and an MTK solution, say exactly that. Don't say "*What are most known ways to...*", because  that attracts an answer for each and every Android vendor, making a list question that has no "right" answer. Also remember that the answer may not even be consistent across all HTC devices, and you may need to get *more* specific.

---

However, I don't understand what exactly this means:

> From the crowd of high-rep specialists: you are doing not what is allowed in public SDK, thus there is no answer.

Nobody in any of those threads says "there is no answer." They say that it's vendor/hardware specific and that your first step should be contacting the manufacturer. Second, nobody answering those questions has over 1000 rep, so I'm not sure if they count as "high-rep specialists." I *have* seen similar answers from high-rep users(and I've said it myself on occasion), but your sample questions don't make this clear.

### Ask a specific question...

By comparison, look at this: [Inject uplink audio in call with Snapdragon MSM8960 SoC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15204570/752320)

The question is specific to a chip, links to related code, and asks for something specific. In return, there is no "you can't do that" in the answer, and an approach is given. The quality of answers is directly related to the quality of the question.

### Conclusion

Take the advice. Contact the manufacturer. They might give you exactly what you need. If so, you can come back and self-answer an *awesome* question to help future visitors, while gaining that sweet rep to boot. If not, at least you can include that as research in your question. When you *do* come back with a question, make it as specific as possible, so that it gets a specific answer.

Remember, you may not get an answer right away. It could take days, weeks, months, who knows? The crowd of kernel hackers is much smaller than the crowd of API users, and it may take some time for anyone who *can* answer your question to actually see it.